# Zen subtheme region templates not being used?

Tags: 7, theming

In a subtheme of Zen, I've got a `templates` folder that has `region.tpl.php` and `region--footer.tpl.php` that are copied from the main Zen theme. However, the custom region file is not being used for the regions of my theme; I even changed the contents of the `region--footer.tpl.php` file to just be `<?php exit("Hi!");` to see if it's being called at all, and it appears to not be.

I've cleared the theme cache (it's set to clear every page load); what am I missing to get that custom region template to actually apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to check on that might be causing your error:

- Is the footer region populated with a box or content? If no, the region won't show.
- Have you edited the `region--footer.tpl.php` of the main Zen theme or your subtheme? Editing the wrong one won't show the result.
- Is the footer properly actived (not commented) in your subthemes's `.info` file? (`regions[footer] = Footer`)

Comment: Thank you, Apex; indeed I didn't have anything in my footer region. For one other custom area, it looks like my issue was that the name of the region had a hyphen in the name, which Zen/Drupal doesn't like. Changing the machine_name of the region to have an underscore instead (and change the custom region template's name) made it start applying.

Comment: You're most welcome ^^

Comment: Upvote? Could use the extra features on this exchange ;)